# How to send multiple rows data from JDBC to oracle stored procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, jdbc, java-stored-procedures

I want to save the multiple rows data in DB using oracle stored procedure from JDBC.

Aware of XML data approach.

**Can we send the list or map from java to database and insert in data base** from stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, We can use the STRUCT Class for Oracle Objects.

For more details, check the below link

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/java.920/a96654/oraoot.htm

Answer (score 0):

There are something like "table value parameter" which can help you storing your multiple rows in DB

Refer this. [This might give you some help](http://www.higherorderlogic.com/2010/02/calling-an-oracle-stored-procedure-with-a-table-parameter-with-springs-storedprocedure-class/)

Comment: See this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10217922/how-to-use-array-table-parameter-to-oracle-odp-net-10g-via-ado-net-c

Comment: required how to achieve this in jdbc?