# IDbDataparameter to use datatable as a return type

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I am trying to use the IDbConnection interface to call a stored procedure to return a table type. The database is an orcale database.

C# code

```
IDbConnection connection = DBFactory.CreateConnection();
connection.Open();
using (IDbCommand comm = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    comm.CommandText = STORE_PROC;
    IDbDataParameter param = comm.CreateParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "P_INPUT";
    param.DbType = DbType.String;
    param.Value = "val";

    IDbDataParameter paramOut = comm.CreateParameter();     
    paramOut.ParameterName = "P_OUTPUT";
    paramOut.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    comm.Parameters.Add(param);
    comm.Parameters.Add(paramOut);
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

att the line comm.ExecuteNonQuery() I get the following error:

```
ORA-06550: Regel 1, kolom 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call
to 'name_stored_procedure'.
ORA-06550: Regel 1, kolom 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

the stored procedure function has the following structure:

```
procedure name_stored_procedure
( p_input       varchar2
, p_output               out   bes_bpr_tabtype
);
```

How can i get the command to return the table type?

Comment: It's not possible to use tables as types in the generic `IDbDataParameter` interface; the method for passing these is provider-specific. If you *know* your database is Oracle, you can use the Oracle-specific ways for it; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10217922/ and/or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557318/ may be relevant.

Comment: Drat, I was hoping there would be a generic solution for this

Comment: A generic solution would be setting `IDbParameter.DbType` to `DbType.Object`, and then your provider should just do the Right Thing when it sees the object passed is a `DataTable`. Unfortunately, this is not how it works for either Oracle or SQL Server (probably because getting a generic `DataTable` to line up with the typed metadata is too much effort).